# Simulation software recommendation to confirm pipeline validity

Tags: simulated-data

I'm trying to detect convergent evolution in different samples of the same species.
I'm just trying to see if past 20 generations the nucleotide frequency of snps under pressure converges somewhat for all samples.
What i want now is to validate my pipeline using a simulation.
I would like to simulate the evolution of populations and see if the pipeline i built would detect the snps from the reads.
I'm using pool-seq and illumina with reads of around 100base pairs.
Can you recommend me some software and maybe point me to the tutorial?